# How print only the current logged in "root" user IP address?

Tags: text-processing

Currently I can see my (root) IP address on top of the output for this command:

```
last
```

But what I want is just that the IP address is printed out to me in a clean way.

```
root     pts/1        1.1.1.1      Tue Aug 19 03:33   still logged in
```

The desire is to simply get:

```
1.1.1.1
```

Comment: `last | awk '/root/ {print $3}'`...

Comment: prints too many ips

Comment: Well you didn't specify exactly what the input would look like, which is why I commented rather than answered.

Comment: it has multiple lines. only first line's is needed

Comment: So exit after the first match: `{print $3; exit}'`

Comment: @jasonwryan, wow great. But for a list of currently logged in users I gave the answer with `w`.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want a list of current remote logins with the  user `root`. The command `w` lists all the logins on a system. So you can manipulate the output using `grep` or something else.

This will provide you the current remote logins of `root` with IP address and also the local logins.

```
w -s root
```

Using `grep` with that output, to achieve the output you require:-

```
w -s root | grep -v ":0"
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, there are a few ways to achieve this. I would use `awk` as follow

```
last | awk '$1 ~ /root/ && /logged/{print $3 | "uniq" ;}'
```

Or

```
last | awk '$1 ~ /root/ && /logged/{a[$3]++}END{ for (i in a) print i}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jasonwryan:

`last | awk ' $1=/root/ {print $3}'|uniq` or
`last | awk ' $1=/root/ {print $3}'|sort -u`

Answer (score -2):

`` last=`last|tail -n <line number desired here>`;last=($last);echo ${last[2]} ``

Comment: I did not downvote you, but can you explain what you have done here please?